# Re-enable TextMate 2 alpha Rails 'rocketship' shortcut

Tags: textmate, rails

After updating to the latest alpha version of TextMate 2, the `control - l` shortcut no longer inserts a rocketship (`=>`)

Is this an option that can be re-enabled, is there another shortcut that does this or is there a bundle that can add this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it turns out that the shortcut had been changed to `control + .` which I guess is supposed to be more logical.

Hope this helps someone in the future.